# Is there anything stopping you from just staying on an island?

Tags: raft

When playing Raft, is there anything stopping you from just staying on an island and ditching the titular raft?

Like staying on an island seems to be a better alternative than being at the mercy of the shark on the raft.

Does anything stop you? Do islands get some kind of calamity after a while making it impossible to stay? Or, is it just impossible to advance in the game if you stay at an island?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you stay on an island, you won't advance the story.** Advancing the story requires exploring the world.

**You'll also eventually run out of food and crafting resources.** Resources such as wood, fruit, and scrap are finite on an island. Once you've harvested everything from the immediate area (island, sea, sea floor), you must set sail to gather more resources.

Toward the later stages of the game, you're able to farm some resources (such as wood and fruit). You and also catch, cook, and eat fish. However:

- Fishing poles require wood & leaves, and chopping down trees requires stone or scrap. You'll eventually run out of stone and scrap if you aren't pulling in barrels or visiting new islands.
- Fruit yields fewer seeds than you used to plan them. Watermelons and pineapples only yield a seed 2/3 of the time when harvested. Mango trees yield a seed 14.3% of the time with every chop, and palm trees yield a seed 11.8% of the time with every chop. At these rates, you'll eventually run out of seeds unless you continue visiting new islands.

References:

- [Mango Seed (via Raft Wiki)](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Mango_Seed)
- [Palm Seed (via Raft Wiki)](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Palm_Seed)
- [Pineapple Seed (via Raft Wiki)](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Pineapple_Seed)
- [Watermelon Seed (via Raft Wiki)](https://raft.gamepedia.com/Watermelon_Seed)
- [Tree farms are totally worth it, but I've been struggling with sustainability of seeds. Tips? (via Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/RaftTheGame/comments/epa2fw/tree_farms_are_totally_worth_it_but_ive_been/)
- [Sustainable gardening? (via Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/RaftTheGame/comments/8o4433/sustainable_gardening/)

Comment: Guess I had a Minecraft mentality where they always give you more than you put in while farming. Seems like raft is the reverse.

Comment: @Fredy31 Aye - the game appears to be designed intentionally to push players back onto the raft, forcing them to deal with the shark.